# how to show record using php with some modify

Tags: php, mysql, select, record

I have record of table in bellow:

```
| id_sub   | id_cri | poin  |
------------------------------
|    S1    |   C1   |   20  |
|    S2    |   C1   |   10  |
|    S1    |   C2   |   15  |
|    S2    |   C2   |   25  |
|    S1    |   C3   |   17  |
|    S2    |   C3   |   10  |
|    S1    |   C4   |   20  |
|    S2    |   C4   |   12  |
```

And I want to show record of table using php as bellow,

```
| Result   | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
--------------------------------
|    S1    | 20 | 15 | 17 | 20 |
|    S2    | 10 | 25 | 10 | 12 |
```

Please help me solve this, sorry my language is bad

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :-)